# Where to implement webhook routes in a feathersjs app?

Tags: feathersjs

Assuming a Feathers app with the following directory structure:

```
- src
-- hooks
-- middleware
-- services
```

Where is an appropriate place to put webhook route handlers? Should this be done using middleware, or would it be more idiomatic to use standard Express routes and put them within a routes directory?

For context, I want to listen to events from Instagram, and they don't necessarily match up with the RESTful services I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A middleware is only a handler for a standard express route. I'd consider a webhook a middleware like any other non-service endpoint.

In that middleware you can retrieve services via `req.app.service`. For example an Instagram webhook that creates entries in the `images` service for the data retrieved by the webhook and then sends the status (or error back) can look like this:

```
app.use('/instagram', function(req, res) {
  const imageService = req.app.service('images');
  const images = req.body.data;

  imageService.create(currentData).then(() => {
    res.status(200);
    res.end('ok');
  }).catch(error => {
    res.status(500);
    res.end(error.message);
  });
});
```

The data sent to the webhook should also be verified with Instagram before adding them to the database.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the quick response!